# Excel Computation on Row Class

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with different classes of objects listed vertically (shown below).

[image]

The NAME is in column 1, the VALUE is in column 2 and the AVERAGE (that I want to compute) is in col 3.

Is there a way to calculate column 3 using a formula (I can't add pivot tables to this)?

Note: 2 is the average value of A's, 5 is the average value of AA's and 9 is avg of B's.

Note2: Average is just an example, *I actually want to identify if a row's value is above x-standard deviations from the class's average.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, in cell C1 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9),"")
```